# Validating sign up pages using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have multiple sign up pages that I am currently testing. Each of the form have seprate fields. However, some share common fields(as you can see from signup page.py).

This is what I have so far(I am using Page Object method), I would like to know how I can improve my code to make it more robust.

Here is the signUp `page.py`:

```
class signupPage(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super(signupPage, self).__init__(driver)

    def SignupPage1139_CompanyOne(self):
        self.driver.get("https://abc.com/s_csignup.jsp?token=XVtQHUUGYFFaRhNaXxJaQVBRZEl2EnBo")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cname").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cname").send_keys("QA EXTERNAL")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cf_2727675").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cf_2727675").send_keys("Test")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cf_2697953").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cf_2697953").send_keys("Test")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("sbbut").click()
        self.assertEqual("Could not create organization, an organization with the entered criteria already exists.", self.close_alert_and_get_its_text())

    def SignupPage1139_CompanyTwo(self):
        self.driver.get("https://abc.com/s_csignup.jsp?token=XVtQHUUGYFFaRhNaXxJaQVBRZElzGnJt")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cname").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cname").send_keys("QA EXTERNAL")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("city").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("city").send_keys("Toronto")
        Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("state")).select_by_visible_text("Ontario")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("sbbut").click()
        self.assertEqual("Cannot update using new scripts as there is already a matching company", self.close_alert_and_get_its_text())

    def SignupPage1139_CompanyThree(self):
        self.driver.get("https://abc.com/s_csignup.jsp?token=XVtQHUUGYFFcRhZdXxJaQVBRZEl9HnRr")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cname").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cname").send_keys("DO NOT DELETE - Pandora External")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cf_2698238").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("cf_2698238").send_keys("000000124")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("sbbut").click()
```

Here is my `test.py`:

```
class MatchingContactCompany(BaseTestCase, unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        super(MatchingContactCompany, self).setUp()


    def test_MatchingCompany(self):
        # form 1
        signup.obj = signupPage(self.driver)
        signup.obj.SignupPage1139_CompanyOne()
        # form 2
        signup.obj.SignupPage1139_CompanyTwo()
        # form 3 create the account and verify if the account was created
        signup.obj.SignupPage1139_CompanyThree()


   def tearDown(self):
       super(MatchingContactCompany, self).tearDown()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is not how the Page Object pattern should be implemented*:

- page object needs to have abstractions over the visual elements on a page
- you should not be asserting things in the page object methods

There are, of course, many different Python+Selenium Page Object pattern implementations and I am not completely sure, which one is the One, here are [some](https://justin.abrah.ms/python/selenium-page-object-pattern--the-key-to-maintainable-tests.html)(1) [of](https://qxf2.com/blog/page-object-model-selenium-python/)(2) [them](https://github.com/gunesmes/page-object-python-selenium/blob/master/pages.py)(3).

We can, at least, start with defining locators and then reusing them inside the methods, something along these lines:

```
class SignupPage(Page):
    cname_input = (By.ID, "cname")

    username_input = (By.ID, "cf_2727675")
    password_input = (By.ID, "cf_2697953")  # assuming this is password

    submit_button = (By.ID, "sbbut")

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super(SignupPage, self).__init__(driver)

    def submit(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*self.submit_button).click()

    def sign_up(self):
        self.driver.get("https://abc.com/s_csignup.jsp?token=XVtQHUUGYFFaRhNaXxJaQVBRZEl2EnBo")

        cname = self.driver.find_element(*self.cname_input)
        cname.send_keys("QA EXTERNAL")

        username = self.driver.find_element(*self.username_input)
        username.clear()
        username.send_keys("Test")

        password = self.driver.find_element(*self.password_input)
        password.clear()
        password.send_keys("Test")

        self.submit()
```

Or, even better, we can create a class for every Page Element, like suggested in the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-object-classes).

Note that the assertion itself should be moved to the test case method, and, hence, your `Page` class should not be derived from the `unittest.TestCase` (or have the `assertEqual` method).

---

Also, here are some notes about the code style of the code in the question:

- if your `BaseTestCase` class inherits `unittest.TestCase` (it should), there is no need for multiple inheritance. And, you would not need to override the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods:

  ```
  class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
      # ...

  class MatchingContactCompany(BaseTestCase):
      def test_matching_company(self):
          # ...
  ```
- according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), a class name should start with a capital letter and be in camel case - call it `SignupPage` instead of `signupPage`
- the `test_*` methods should be named according to the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id46) method name convention - it should be `test_matching_company` instead of `test_MatchingCompany`
- same note about your page object methods - use a lower case and separate words with underscore